# NSArray only changed if class is passed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class with a NSArray property using ARC with nothing fancy...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyClass : NSObject
property(nonatomic, strong) (NSArray *) myArray;
@end

#import "MyClass.h"
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;
@end
```

If an attempt is made to use a method inside of another class to try to set that array it does not set it if only the array is passed; however,  it does set if the class is passed, I'm not sure why that is....

The code that attempts this both ways is below...

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[self setArrayByPassingArray:myClass.myArray];
NSLog (@"%@", myClass.myArray)
//result is null

[self setArrayByPassingClass:myClass];
NSLog (@"%@", myClass.myArray)
//result is test, test2...

-(void)setArrayByPassingArray:(NSArray *)arrayToSet {
arrrayToSet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test", @"test2", nil];
}

-(void)setArrayByPassingClass:(MyClass *)classWithArrayToSet {
classWithArrayToSet.myArray = = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test", @"test2", nil];
}
```

I tried some other methods with just strings and the strings are not changed, so I'm not sure why they are changed if class containing them is passed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setArrayByPassingArray:` method in the first example assigns the newly created `NSArray` to its *parameter*, which is passed *by value*, and is promptly discarded upon exiting from the method. What happens here is that a copy of the reference to `myArray` is made (not a copy of the array, only a copy of a reference to that array) before calling `setArrayByPassingArray:`. That copy is no longer attached to the `myArray` member of `MyClass`.

Your second example is not passing a class - it's passing *an instance* of the class, and then it correctly uses the dot notation to assign the `myArray` property in your instance. That's why this second example works, and the first example does not.

If you use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` throughout your program, you can rewrite your first example to make it work:

```
-(void)setArrayByPassingArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayToSet {
    [arrrayToSet setArray:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test", @"test2", nil]];
}
```

Comment: @Nick You need to make `myArray` an `NSMutableArray`. I also forgot to fix the signature of the `setArrayByPassingArray` - I edited it now.

Comment: NSMutableArray also did not work, but changing it to -(void)changeArray:(NSMutableArray **)array {
    *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", @"test2", nil ]; and then using &array, so that it is passing a pointer...thanks for all your help
}

-(void)changeArray2:(NSArray **)array {
    *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", @"test2", nil ];

}

Comment: @Nick The trick with pointer to pointer should have worked, that's how "poor man's pass by reference" works in C and Objective C. The trick with `NSMutualArray` should work too: make sure the method calls `setArray` instead of performing an assignment.

Comment: Why does the class instance pass by reference, but a pointer to pointer is required to change objects like NSString?  I will try using the Class methods on a NSString passed in to see.

Comment: @Nick Class instance is passed by value as well, so if you assigned to it, nothing would happen. But you did not assign to it: instead, you are calling `[classWithArrayToSet setmyArray:...]` on it using the dot notation for accessing properties.